# R and filter, rbind

Tags: r, filter

I study R and do some project. I want filtering from many values with time so I wrote below. But occur some error and I don't solution. I need help.

This is value list.

```
divvy_trips <- c("divvy_trips_2013","divvy_trips_2014_Q1Q2","divvy_trips_2014_Q3_07","divvy_trips_2014_Q3_0809","divvy_trips_2014_Q4","divvy_trips_2015_Q1","divvy_trips_2015_Q2","divvy_trips_2015_07","divvy_trips_2015_08","divvy_trips_2015_09","divvy_trips_2015_Q4","divvy_trips_2016_Q1","divvy_trips_2016_04","divvy_trips_2016_05","divvy_trips_2016_06","divvy_trips_2016_Q3","divvy_trips_2016_Q4","divvy_trips_2017_Q1","divvy_trips_2017_Q2","divvy_trips_2017_Q3","divvy_trips_2017_Q4","divvy_trips_2018_Q1","divvy_trips_2018_Q2","divvy_trips_2018_Q3","divvy_trips_2018_Q4","divvy_trips_2019_Q1","divvy_trips_2019_Q2","divvy_trips_2019_Q3","divvy_trips_2019_Q4")


divvy_trip_days=NULL  
    for(i in divvy_trips){

        trip<-eval(parse(text=i))

        if ("starttime" %in% names(trip)){

            trip<-select(trip,usertype) %>%
               filter(((hour(starttime) >=6 & hour(stoptime) >=6) & (hour(starttime)<=10 & 
               hour(stoptime) <=10)) |((hour(starttime) >=16& hour(stoptime) >=16)& (hour(starttime)<=20 & hour(stoptime) <=20)))%>% 
               group_by(usertype,what_day = wday(starttime))%>% 
               summarise(count=n())
         }
         divvy_trip_days <- rbind(divvy_trip_days,trip)
         print(str(i))
  }
```

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `|...`.
x object 'starttime' not found

Comment: `select(trip,usertype) ` selects only the column `usertype` from `trip`. There won't be any other columns (so also no column named starttime). Also, I'd suggest looking into `get`.

Comment: thank. your think is using select() with columns like starttime,stoptime and so on?

Comment: Not sure why you'd need a select here anyways, but yea, if you choose to use select you need to select all the columns you want to use

Comment: I think select some column make reduce of computing time. but you know that is no need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer without a sample or details about your data but you may try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

mget(divvy_trips) %>%
  map_df(~{
    if ("starttime" %in% names(.x)){
    .x <- .x %>%
      filter(((hour(starttime) >=6 & hour(stoptime) >=6) & 
                (hour(starttime)<=10 & hour(stoptime) <=10)) |
               ((hour(starttime) >=16 & hour(stoptime) >=16) & 
                (hour(starttime)<=20 & hour(stoptime) <=20))) %>% 
      count(usertype,what_day = wday(starttime), name = 'count')
    }
    .x
  }) -> divvy_trip_days

divvy_trip_days
```

If all the dataframes in `divvy_trips` contains the column `starttime` then you may skip the `if` step.